# TAX Calculation on bundled additions

Tags: tax, rounding

We have a Magento set at applying TAX per item - then totaling the cart value. This helps greatly with rounding issues.

But

This does not seem to be calculated this way with bundled product additions to a product.

ie, I have a product that is 9.50 including Tax
I add an item (Custom option) that is another product with a price of 1.99

I would expect a total of 11.49

But, it is showing as 11.50 in the cart. It seems to adding the 2 ex TAX values together, then adding tax and totaling.

How can we set the adding of a item to an existing product to follow the same rul of apply Tax to items first - then total ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom options changes the initial price of product. Instead you can create Bundle product with Dynamic price, one taxable simple product (9.50 including tax) and one non-taxable simple product (1.99). Then you can add this products as bundle items with *checkbox* **input type** to your bundle product. First product as required and second as optional.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, will play with some options as you say and see what happens. Many thanks